# Como criar uma Stored Procedure para duas tabelas

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando fazer essa Stored Procedure, mas está dando erro.

Eu consigo fazer um insert com proceder?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `centralrit`.`sp_InterdDetalhe_Encrypt` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `centralrit`.`sp_InterdDetalhe_Encrypt`
  (
  in p_id int(11),
  in p_usuario_id int(11),
  in p_nome text,
  in p_cpf text,
  in p_nome_pai text,
  in p_nome_mae text,
  in p_data_cadastro datetime,
  in p_serventia_id int,
  in p_natureza text,
  in p_livro text,
  in p_folha text,
  in p_termo text,
  in p_ativo TINYINT(1),
  in p_lixeira TINYINT(1)
 )
BEGIN
  insert into interditado
  (usuario_id, nome, cpf, nome_pai, nome_mae, data_cadastro)
  values
  (
    p_usuario_id,
    aes_encrypt(p_nome, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
    aes_encrypt(p_cpf, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
    aes_encrypt(p_nome_pai, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
    aes_encrypt(p_nome_mae, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
    p_data_cadastro
  );

insert into interditado_detalhe (interditado_id, usuario_id, serventia_id, data_cadastro as cadastro_detalhe,
natureza, livro, folha, termo, ativo, lixeira) values
  (
    p_id,
    p_usuario_id,
    p_serventia_id,
    p_data_cadastro,
    aes_encrypt(p_natureza, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
    aes_encrypt(p_livro, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
    aes_encrypt(p_folha, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
    aes_encrypt(p_termo, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
    p_ativo,
    p_lixeira
  );

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

> Erro: Script line: 4  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'as cadastro_detalhe, natureza, livro, folha,
>   termo, ativo, lixeira) values   (' at line 33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, você consegue fazer qualquer CRUD com uma Stored Procedure para duas tabelas ou até mais ou até mesmo o uso de CRUD (create, read, update e delite), em uma unica Stored Procedure.

O seu erro é porque você esta tentando renomear sua coluna em um INSERT, isso só é possível fazer em um SELECT, para os casos de INSERT, UPDATE OU DELETE (where*), não é necessário que você renomeie suas colunas.

Resumindo você não precisar renomear suas colunas nesses casos.

Altere sua Procedure para.

```
 DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `centralrit`.`sp_InterdDetalhe_Encrypt` $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `centralrit`.`sp_InterdDetalhe_Encrypt`
      (
          in p_id int(11),
          in p_usuario_id int(11),
          in p_nome text,
          in p_cpf text,
          in p_nome_pai text,
          in p_nome_mae text,
          in p_data_cadastro datetime,
          in p_serventia_id int,
          in p_natureza text,
          in p_livro text,
          in p_folha text,
          in p_termo text,
          in p_ativo TINYINT(1),
          in p_lixeira TINYINT(1)
     )

    BEGIN
        insert into interditado (usuario_id, nome, cpf, nome_pai, nome_mae, data_cadastro)
        values
        (
            p_usuario_id,
            aes_encrypt(p_nome, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
            aes_encrypt(p_cpf, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
            aes_encrypt(p_nome_pai, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
            aes_encrypt(p_nome_mae, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
            p_data_cadastro
        );

        insert into interditado_detalhe (interditado_id, usuario_id, serventia_id, 
        data_cadastro, natureza, livro, folha, termo, ativo, lixeira) values
        (
            p_id,
            p_usuario_id,
            p_serventia_id,
            p_data_cadastro,
            aes_encrypt(p_natureza, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
            aes_encrypt(p_livro, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
            aes_encrypt(p_folha, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
            aes_encrypt(p_termo, 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC'),
            p_ativo,
            p_lixeira
        );

    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

O segundo `insert` está com erro de sintaxe.
Remova o `as cadastro_detalhe` que funcionará.

```
insert into interditado_detalhe 
(interditado_id, usuario_id, serventia_id, data_cadastro /*as cadastro_detalhe*/,
natureza, livro, folha, termo, ativo, lixeira) 
values (...)
```